# Binding Command to ViewModel inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I want to bind a `UserControl` to a ViewModel to use Commands/Events.
My application consists of a `MainWindow` with a `ContentControl` inside, which is used to display a `UserControls` (the actual content) for navigation purposes.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="">
            <View: />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Connection" Command="..." />
    </Menu>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public ICommand MenuCommand;

    private object _SelectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return _SelectedViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ICommand = new RelayCommand(MenuClick);
    }

    private void MenuClick(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new ConnectionViewModel();
    }
}
```

This is how the navigation of my app works. The only problem I'm having is that I can't seem
to use Commands (`Button` for example) in the `UserControl` itself.

ConnectionView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Content="Button" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ConnectionViewModel.cs

```
class ConnectionViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public ICommand ButtonCommand;

    public ConnectionViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonClick);
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
    }
}
```

I can fill `ListViews` in the `UserControl` View but I can't get the `Button` Command working. What exactly is the problem, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ButtonCommand` must be a property for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }
```

You have defined it as a field:

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand;
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thank you